# Count number of selected images on file upload

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="upload" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Now when i choose i.e. 5 images, how can I get that number with jquery? So when it's chosen, I want to write

> 5 images chosen.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbxgg/)**

Use `files.length`

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
  console.log($(this)[0].files.length);
});
```

Comment: Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day...

Comment: @JamesHill, I had already flagged it. But just did not want it to be left unanswered.

Comment: I hear ya. I think questions like this should go unanswered. Closed or not (and it will be), an answer encourages more low-quality questions where no attempt has been made.